# Информация о каскадном удалении в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Здравствуйте.

Никто не знает, можно ли как-то для PostgreSQL с помощью системных таблиц узнать, есть ли для определенной таблицы в таблицах, ссылающихся на нее, установленное каскадное удаление?

Просто нужно узнать, при удалении определенной записи, какие еще записи удалились каскадно.

Answer (score 0):

для проверки `ON DELETE`:

```
SELECT
 constraint_catalog,constraint_catalog,constraint_name,table_catalog,table_schema,table_name,column_name,delete_rule
FROM  information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu
INNER JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints rc
USING (constraint_catalog, constraint_schema, constraint_name)
WHERE delete_rule <> 'NO ACTION';
```

Comment: Можно так, как Вы предлагаете. Я решил это таким образом: SELECT tc.table_name, kcu.column_name
  FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc JOIN 
       information_schema.key_column_usage kcu 
       ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name JOIN 
       information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu 
       ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name JOIN 
       information_schema.referential_constraints rc 
       ON tc.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name 
  WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND 
 ccu.table_name = 'ИнтересующаяТаблица' AND 
 rc.delete_rule = 'CASCADE';